# Como remover auto complete de input do google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, input, autocompletar

Quero remover background amarelo de quando esta habilitado o auto complete do Google Chrome.
Tentei desabilitar o auto complete, aplicando: `autocomplete="off"` e não tive sucesso.

[image: Essa é a visualização de como é pra ficar. Esse print foi tirado do Firefox]

[image: Visualização no Chrome]

A imagem de cima é a visualização no Chrome e a debaixo é no Firefox, como é pra ficar.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jmn2d213/2/. Cara, não precisa repetir os campos. Isso é a maior gambiarra que eu já vi em HTML. Coloca `autocomplete="off"` na tag `<form>`. Veja o Link no JsFiddle.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Como dito [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938891/disable-autofill-in-chrome-without-disabling-autocomplete) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill), parece que atualmente o Google Chrome ignora qualquer tipo de atributo `autocomplete="off"`, por mais que isso pareça estranho.

Então uma solução (alternativa) para fazer com que o Chrome não faça um autocomplete é criando 2 campos seguidos com o mesmo `name=""`, um com `display="none"`(que não será visto pelo usuário) e outro normal, algo assim:

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email_fake" class="hidden" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;" />
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password_fake" class="hidden" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;" />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

[<kbd>Exemplo também disponível no jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/jmn2d213/).

**Atualização 2017**

Parece que nas versões atuais do Google Chrome (Testei na **59.0.3071.104**), é possível resolver isso desta forma:

- **`autocomplete="off"` na tag `form`:**

```html
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

[<kbd>Também no jsFiddle.</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/e6t87d1p/)

Comment: Obrigado @Fernando!

Comment: Oloco. Sério isso ? É só colocar `autocomplete="off"` ou `autocomplete="false"` na tag do `<form>`. Nem a pau vou fazer isso. Eu faço assim e funciona.

Comment: Ok @TaoPaiPai, esse resposta era verdade quando ela foi criada, se há uma melhor forma de obter o mesmo resultado, você pode criar uma resposta atualizada, com exemplo e demonstrando!

Comment: Essa alternativa realmente é uma "gambiarra", mas quando tem um email e um password na mesma tela parece que o Chrome entende que é um login... Nos outros caso só o autocomplete="off" funciona.

Answer (score 6):

Uma outra solução que encontrei foi desabilitar o campo, o que faz com que o autocomplete não funcione em nenhum navegador (testei no Chrome, no FF e no IE).

Depois basta habilitar o campo quando o formulário estiver carregado, porque nesse ponto o navegador já não vai mais preencher os campos:

```
<input type="email" id="email" disabled="disabled" />
```

E no `Javascript`, após carregar o documento, habilitar o campo. Neste exemplo, usando `jQuery`:

```
// Esperar o documento carregar
$(document).ready(function () {
   // Usando um pequeno delay de 100ms porque às vezes o navegador preenche o campo logo que o documento está pronto, e pode não funcionar como esperado
   setTimeout(function(){
     $('#email').removeAttr('disabled');
   }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Apenas convertendo em puro JS:
    function sleep (time) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }   

    sleep(400).then(async() => { 
        document.getElementsByName('email')[0].disabled=false;
    });

Answer (score 5):

Tentei muitas alternativas e cheguei nesta:

Normalmente se coloca autocomplete="off" ou autocomplete="on"

Então coloquei

autocomplete="no"

Deu certo.

Comment: Funcionou para mim. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade apenas colocar logo após resolve `<input style="display: none;" />`, porém quando você insere uma info ele ja fica com o fundo amarelo.

Use isto:

```
input:-webkit-autofill 
{    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #f9fbfd inset !important;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #4D90FE !important;
}
```

Comment: Pode complementar um pouco mais sua resposta? O que o trecho do código faz exatamente?

Answer (score 2):

Tentei colocar o autocomplete na tag form como o colega citou e não funcionou. Fiz a duplicação **somente** do email e funcionou para a senha também. Não precisa fazer para a senha. Fim dos problemas com campos amarelos no Chrome, acredito que em outros navegadores também. Desta forma deu certo:

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email_fake" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;" />
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

O autocomplete="off" pode não funcionar em diversos casos.

Eu resolvi adicionando este javascript depois do onload da página:

```
var randomicAtomic = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
  $('input[type=text]').attr('autocomplete',randomicAtomic);
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa que utilizo e considero simples, seria colocando um tempo de espera e limpando os valores dos campos, já que existe um pequeno intervalo até o navegador autocompletar com as sugestões, ficaria da seguinte forma:

Com JQuery

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#user').val('');
  $('#pass').val('');
},420);
```

Sem JQuery

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('user').value = '';
  document.getElementById('pass').value = '';
},420);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

Depois de testar algumas das opções apresentadas aqui, cheguei em uma solução em Js utilizando como base o apresentado pelo Ricardo Pontual, mas aplicando de uma forma que ficasse melhor no entendimento futuro.

Para ajustar, adicione o "autocomplete='off'" no input que deseja remover o AutoComplete e em seguida, adicione esse Script ao .js:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
   let input = document.querySelector('input[autocomplete="off"]');

   input.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

   setTimeout(function(){
      input.removeAttribute('disabled');
   }, 1000)
});
```

Ele irá adicionar o "disabled" a todos os inputs  com o "autocomplete" definido como "off" e após 1 segundo (tempo comum para o Chrome tentar preencher) irá remover o "disabled".

Answer (score -4):

Consegui resolver colocando apenas um espaço no campo e-mail no value, como o navegador não encontra um e-mail que é um espaço, ele não preenche nada e esse espaço o próprio navegador limpa no submit, segue abaixo código:

```html
<form method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value=" " />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
</form>
```

Comment: Esse espaço aí vai acabar inutilizando o `placeholder`.