# Desabilitar o autocomplete de formulários

Tags: javascript, html, autocompletar

Olá... Estou com um problema que eu achava simples, mas estou há dois dias procurando uma solução...

Simplesmente não consigo fazer com que o autocomplete de formulários seja desativado. Eu lembrava do 'autocomplete="off"' pra isso, mas não funciona mais.

Alguém tem uma alternativa pra eu fazer isso no site? (não importa a linguagem, o HTML vai ser o mesmo no final das contas).

PS: Para o Chrome, o código abaixo faz o trabalho:

```
        $("input[autocomplete='off']").each(function () {

            var input = $(this);
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var name = $(this).attr("name");

            input.removeAttr("name").removeAttr("id");

            setTimeout(function () {
                input.attr("name", name).attr("id", id);
            }, 1);

        });
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Como esse atributo não é válido pela W3C o pessoal costuma inserir o autocomplete="off" via javascript:   campo.setAttribute('autocomplete','off');

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61510/como-remover-auto-complete-de-input-do-google-chrome

Comment: Pois é... Eu vi essa "solução" e fiquei abismado. Mas vai ser o jeito. Vou aplicar essa solução na segunda feira.

Answer (score 0):

passei pelo mesmo problema, hoje 10/09/2019 única solução que encontrei foi essa

colocar 2 inputs falsos antes do seu input

```
<input class="hidden" type="text" style="display: none!important; visibility: hidden!important;" ></input>
<input class="hidden" type="password" style="display: none!important; visibility: hidden!important;" ></input>
```

Answer (score -1):

O `autocomplete="off"` ainda funciona, mas tambem pode tentar com jQuery.

```
$( document ).on( 'focus', ':input', function(){
        $( this ).attr( 'autocomplete', 'off' );
    });
```

Comment: Então, mas se você tiver um campo texto e um campo senha, não funciona mais. Está na documentação do Google Chrome. E parece que o IE também seguiu por esse caminho.

Answer (score -1):

O `autocomplete=off` sozinho para mim também não funciona! Mas em conjuntos com as outras opções funciona!!! Extrai essa linha colada acima, da tela de login do scanner de vulnerabilidades nessus, la o `autocomplete` está `off`! Nem tive o trabalho de ler sobre cada opção da input do exemplo acima, apenas copiei, adaptei nos meus codes.

Comment: Entenda seu código não funciona. Você pensa que ele funciona porque o buffer de autocompletar do seu browser para o `input` cujo o atributo `name` é igual a `Login` está vazio e já estava vazio quando implementou o código. O `autoclomplete=off` ele previne o UA de iniciar um buffer de autocompletar para um determinado name. A partir do momento que você completa e faz o submit dum input com `autoclomplete=on` é iniciado o buffer de autocompletar e o `autoclomplete=off`nunca mais volta a funcionar para esse input até o momento que você esvaziar o cache e todos os buffers do navegador.

Comment: faça o teste `<input type="text" placeholder="Login" name="login" maxlength="128" autocomplete="on" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" class="form-control" aria-label="Login" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">` veja que funciona igual uma praga.

Answer (score -2):

De acordo com o o [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp), este é um comportamento padrão, e devia sim, estar funcionando.

```
<form action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="on"> <!-- este está habilitado -->
First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><!-- Já este não --><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Tente verificar as tags, muitos podem ser os riscos que podem ocasionar isso.

Comment: Isso não funciona, vc pode ver que na própria pergunta o autor diz: *"Eu lembrava do 'autocomplete="off"' pra isso, mas não funciona mais."*  Vc ao menos testou a sua resposta para testar e ver se funciona? Nem no site da própria w3School isso da certo, é só vc ir lá e testar! http://prntscr.com/n0ym4i