# autocomplete="off" não funciona

Tags: php, html

Possuo dois campos:

```
<label>Imagem do perfil:</label>
<input><input type="file" value="<?php echo $img; ?>" name="img[]"/><br/>

<label>Senha:</label>
<input type="password" value="<?php echo $senha; ?>"/>
```

Ao atualizar a página, o campo "Imagem do perfil" é prenchido com o usuário "X" armazenado em cache, e da mesma forma a senha. Sendo que o certo seria, o campo "Imagem do perfil" estar nulo e a "Senha" preenchida com a do usuário "Y".

**Obs.**:

1ª Estou logado com o usuário "Y".

2ª Isso ocorre quando a variável `$img` está vazia ou o `value` do input nulo.

3ª Possuo outras senhas identicas ao do usuário "Y" armazenadas em cache.

Comment: campo "imagem do perfil"? Não seria o campo value do input do label  "Imagem do perfil"?

Comment: Sim, pois para o usuário o campo é: "Imagem do perfil", por isso as aspas duplas. rs'

Comment: hehehe, mas não somos usuários, kkk

Comment: veja esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61510/como-remover-auto-complete-de-input-do-google-chrome

Comment: esse $senha vem de um session?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo realmente a gambiarra funcionou, porém existe alguma atualização, tendo em vista que a "Atualização 2017" da solução não funciona?

Comment: tem essa gambiarra também autocomplete="new-password"    <input type="password" value="<?php echo $senha; ?>" autocomplete="new-password" />

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, a senha vem do BD, até porque não é seguro guardar dados críticos em sessões, certo? Já sobre o `autocomplete="new-password"`, não funcionou.

Comment: Ta usando o Chrome? A senha e img do usuário estão gravados no gerenciador de senhas do Chrome? Esse gerenciador tem problemas com campo password, ele entende que o campo anterior o da senha sempre será o de login e preenchera mesmo que esteja com autocomplete off. Você pode colocar um campo tipo password oculto no meio do form que o chrome se perderá e nao vai preencher nenhum campo.

Comment: @BrunoFolle, foi exatamente o que pensei. rsrs' Obrigado pelo comentário.