# Alterar o background do input preenchido pelo autocomplete do Chrome

Tags: css

Estou a criar um formulário, e como é de conhecimento de todos que, o navegador tem a opção  *"preenchimento automático"*, até ai tudo bem, mas me deparei com a seguinte situação:

[image: Campo com fundo amarelo]

Como podem notar na imagem acima, o campo que foi preenchido automaticamente, ficou com o fundo amarelo e convenhamos concordar que muitas das vezes essa situação desfavorece por simplesmente ter uma cor que não faz parte do design.

Em uma pesquisa aqui no *SOpt*, encontrei esse [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61514/60376) na pergunta [Como remover auto complete de input do google Chrome?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61510), mas não é o que eu preciso, pois não quero desabilitar a opção *"preenchimento automático"*.

Minha pergunta: É possível mudar a cor do fundo sem desabilitar a opção  *"preenchimento automático"*? Se sim: Como fazer isso ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É possível alterar o CSS dos campos que são preenchidos automaticamente com o seguinte código:

```
/* Cor de fundo do autocomplete */
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset;
}

/* Cor do texto do autocomplete */
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: blue !important;
}
```

> É necessário colocar alguma cor pois no momento não é possível colocar o *background-color* transparente.

Answer (score 6):

Recentemente o Chrome trocou a cor do *autofill* dos `inputs` para um tom de Azul Claro, mas aparentemente as técnicas antigas continuam a funcionar...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vou postar apenas uma alternativa que achei legal, e as vezes pode ser mais útil para alguém. A ideia aqui é é já que o `input` tem uma cor, mesmo que seja a cor definida pelo `user-agent`, vc ainda assim pode usar um rotação da matriz de cor de entrada original e basicamente ter qualquer cor, vc ainda pode colocar mais de um filtro como o `saturate()` para ter cores ainda mais acentuadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre o filtro `hue-rotate()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate

Segue o código

```css
[type="password"],
[type="email"] {
    filter: saturate(1) hue-rotate(0deg);
    animation: nome 5s infinite linear;

/* cor original do User-Agent do Chrome */
    background-color: rgb(232, 240, 254) !important;
/* estylos não obrigatórios */
    min-height: 52px;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    
}
@keyframes nome {
    0% {
        filter: saturate(1) hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        filter: saturate(10) hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
```

```html
<input type="email" value="seu email" name="" id="">
<br><br>
<input type="password" value="password" name="" id="">
```

Answer (score 4):

Dessa forma fica com fundo transparente e a cor do texto preta.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border: 1px solid white;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para completar a resposta do @LaércioLopes também é possível alterar a cor do fundo dos campo `select` e `textarea` que foram preenchidos automaticamente.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #FFF inset;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Vi que a solução do @samuel-prado-almeida somente retarda a sobreposição total de cor por parte do browser, mas não soluciona, mas encontrei uma solução, citada nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205976/1476872

Seguindo isso, fiz essa escolha de cores bem bizarras para ter certeza da modificação.

```
  input:-webkit-autofill,
  input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
  input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
  input:-webkit-autofill:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px black inset !important;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: yellow !important;
  }
```

Detalhe importante: você deve dar um F5, mesmo que você faça uso do LiveReload.