# Impedir o autocomplete do navegador

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Há como impedir, através de código, que o navegador faça sugestões de preenchimento no formulário de login?

É que o sistema vai ser usado em laboratórios e seria chato o navegador ficar sugerindo todos os CPF anteriormente cadastrados. Além disso fica um fundo amarelo feio quando o dado vem de sugestão. Veja

Utilizo JSF + componentes primefaces, e mesmo com o autocomplete off no inputText, parece não servir de nada!

Comment: [Alterar o background do input preenchido pelo autocomplete do Chrome](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256541).

Comment: O de alterar cor até foi, mas o de colocar autocomplete off ou false no form não serviu

Comment: No campo de senha deixa assim o atributo `autocomplete="new-password"` veja se funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode fazer assim

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```

Documentação sobre o autocomplete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: Coloquei, mas não serviu, vi em alguns posts que o Chrome está ignorando esses autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

O próprio primefaces tem uma tag autocomplete então em vez de colocar o autocomplete="off" do html, você pode aproveitar a própria tag do primefaces usando o autocomplete="false" conforme a documentação.

Referência - https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/autoComplete.html

Exemplo:

```html
<p:inputText type="text" autocomplete="false" ... />
```