# Como tirar fundo o branco, quando seleciono logins salvos na página de login

Tags: css, html5, css3

Boa noite galera!

To com uma dúvida que não consigo resolver sozinho.

Na minha tela de login, quando eu digito o login, o background do input continua do jeito que eu estilizei. Mas quando eu seleciono um login que estava salvo, o background do input volta ao estilo padrão dele.

Essa primeira imagem, é a forma quando eu digito o login, sem selecionar a opção que o navegador me dá.

[image: Forma com quando eu digito o login]

Nessa segunda imagem, é a forma que fica quando eu seleciono a opção que o navegador me dá

[image: Forma quando eu seleciono a opção que ficou salva]

Gostaria de saber, como eu faço para tirar esse defeito para ficar dá forma que eu estilizei.

Comment: Outro https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256541/alterar-o-background-do-input-preenchido-pelo-autocomplete-do-chrome Antigamente ainda se consegui mudar isso, mas hoje em dia isso é padrão do Browser e do User-agent, não é mais possível alterar isso até onde eu sei...

Comment: Cara, eu nem me preocuparia com isso. O que importa é a aparência inicial. Se o navegador muda isso, deixa ele ser feliz. Vc fez a sua parte rs.

Comment: Ou então, quer apelar com o navegador? Use divs editáveis e inputs escondidos (tipo `hidden`).

Comment: Entendi.vlw galera, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Consegui dar uma tapeada rsrsrs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo bem meu querido? Então, esse é um padrão que indica que o texto foi selecionado usando o autocomplete, mas da pra "tapear" essa cor padrão e deixar ela 'invisível', cria uma class para o seu input, Ex.:

```
<input type="text" name="user" class="meu_input">
```

Chama o input no CSS usando a class que você criou, depois basta colar essa linha aqui, deve resolver o seu problema, Ex.:

```
.meu_input{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, Abraços!

Comment: Vlw, muito obrigado pela ajuda 

Comment: Ajudou para caramba 

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado!